# Create hard/soft links in HDF5 C++ A{O

Tags: c++, hdf5

I have an H5::Dataset which I wan't to make it accessible from several H5::Groups. I know this is possible using hard or soft link, but I am completely out of ideas on how to add this link using the C++ API.

I have seen that in Python one can do

```
grp["name"] = h5py.SoftLink(target_path)
```

but I can't find anything similar in C++.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not bound to a specific API, you may want to try [HDFql](https://www.hdfql.com) as it greatly alleviates users from HDF5 low-level details. Using HDFql in C++, your issue could be solved as follows:

```
// create an HDF5 file named 'test.h5' and use (i.e. open) it 
HDFql::execute("create and use file test.h5");

// create a dataset named 'dset' of data type integer which stores value '10'
HDFql::execute("create dataset dset as int values(10)");

// create three groups named 'grp1', 'grp2' and 'grp3'
HDFql::execute("create group grp1, grp2, grp3");

// create a (soft) link named 'lnk' in groups 'grp1', 'grp2' and 'grp3' (all these links point to dataset 'dset')
HDFql::execute("create link grp1/lnk, grp2/lnk, grp3/lnk to /dset, /dset, /dset");
```

Comment: I already have some code written using C++ API, so if possible, I would prefer to keep using HDF5 C/C++ APIs.